# How to subtract time values in Angular 6 template

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I have two time values. One getting from the API, other time is entered by the user. 
I want to subtract these two values and display the time difference. 
How do I subtract in Angular 6.

Code -

```
<input type="datetime-local" formControlName="timeOfDispatch" class="form-control">
<input type="datetime-local" formControlName="factoryReceiveTime"(focusout)="calculateTime()" class="form-control">
```

Angular -

```
const timeOfResponse = 
this.harvestWeighmentForm.controls.factoryReceiveTime.value;
const timeOfCall = this.harvestWeighmentForm.controls.timeOfDispatch.value;
console.log(timeOfResponse - timeOfCall);
```

When I am doing this, I am getting NaN.

Comment: What things have you tried so far? In general it is helpful to post your current code, what you have tried, and the current error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done in Typescript.

```
function timeDifference(d1: Date, d2: Date):number {
  return +d1 - +d2;
}
```

This returns time difference in milliseconds.

Let me know if it helps.